# Panda portable washing machine not starting the rinse cycle but will run on every other cycle

Tags: washing-machine

I have a portable Panda washing machine that I recently purchased we used it for a couple months and it started stopping right at the rent cycle it would try and fill the tub up with water while the tub was spinning for the rent cycle but no water would come out it would flash e 2 and when I did the research it said a lid closed sensor I adjusted that I fixed that but it still has issues filling up with water during the rent cycle but Phil's just fine on the wash any suggestions or has anybody experienced this similar problem